# <select> options not showing up. DevTools shows not written "Style display = none"

Tags: html, css

I have 2  lists that are not shown, and when I go to chromes or firefox devtools a "Style display = none" is active, but I don't have it written in the original code anywhere. Any clues as to why this is happening?
Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
     <!-- Contenedor Marca-->

  <div  class="container-fluid">
    <div  style="text-align: center;"  class="boxMarca">Marca:</div>

        <select  name="mar"  class="marca"  id="idmar"  onchange="cambmod()">
            <option  value="Todos">Todos</option>
        </select>

     </div>

    <!-- Contenedor Modelo-->
    <div  class="container-fluid">
    <div  style="text-align: center;"  class="boxModelo">Modelo:</div>

        <select name="mod" class="modelo" id="idmod">
            <option value="Todos">Todos</option> 
        </select>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    /*inicio forma buscarMovil*/
#forma_buscar {background:url(../imagenes/forma_buscar.png); margin-top:10px;}  
.categoria {float:right; font-size: medium; position: static; width: 50%; height: 10vh;}
.marca {float:right; font-size: medium; position: static; width: 50%; height: 10vh;}
```

The cambmod() funtion is to retrieve the options from a database.

Comment: I think more code or a link is needed for us to help you determine that.  It must be JS manipulating the DOM somewhere.  But if you have no JS, then sometimes browser plugins/extensions are culprits.

Comment: If your `cambmod()` function retrieves options from a database, why are you calling it with `onchange`? The `onchange` event is called when the value of an element has changed - meaning you need to be able to change the value of `select` before it gets called. Right now you only have one `option` for your `select` elements, meaning you cannot change their value and thus call the `onchange` event.

Comment: @jritchey I have 3 selects (a, b, c) when I change the value of a, b gets updated, and when I change the value of b, c gets updates.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Are you able to create a jsfiddle or a codepen with your code and recreate the issue? As BjornJohnson stated, more code is needed for us to help you determine the issue.